# ASP.NET auto width control

Tags: asp.net, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I have an ASP.NET control, for example a DropDownList. I want to set the width of the control to `auto`. How do I achieve this? The `Width` property in ASP.NET control does not seem to accept `auto`, but it can only accept like percentage, pixels, and points.

I know I can make some workaround by specifying `style="width:auto"` as the control's attribute, and as this attribute is not a valid attribute for the control, it will not be parsed by asp.net and hence passed directly to browser. Is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: When you say width, what's the difference between auto and 100%?

Comment: It's different. I am putting the control inside a `<th>` element. Setting the width with 100% will make the control occupy the whole `<th>` width, whereas for auto it only takes up the necessary space (according to the content of the dropdownlist).

Comment: @rcs you can read my answer for auto width according to the content of the ddl. Good luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few alternatives:

- Adding the `style=width:auto;` into the ASP.NET webcontrol, as mentioned in the question
- Adding `element.Attributes.Add('style', 'width:auto');` in the code behind. Generally it is the same as option number 1, just that it's added from code behind. But option 1 seems to be better because it does not mix presentation with code behind, and changing the presentation does not require recompiling of the program.
- Remove the `Width` property for the ASP.NET control. If the `Width` property is not specified, it will be set as `auto`. But here we need to be careful if there is any CSS rule that may affect the behavior, for example we specify `input` in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

These links might help you:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-auto-width.html

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/dropdownautowidth/defaultcs.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5801/Adjust-combo-box-drop-down-list-width-to-longest-s

**UPDATE**

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/dropdownlist/how-to-make-the-dropdownlist-width-auto-resize.aspx

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?48901-Setting-Drop-Down-List-Width-To-Auto

Please do not forget to comment that which of these links helped you. This will be beneficial for others.

Comment: Please extract the relevant information from these links and put it into your answer. Otherwise a link to google.com would have done also.

Comment: @asma. The links mostly use 3rd-party component, whereas I'm using original .NET webcontrol. The third one is far more complicated than just putting `style="width:auto"`.